# CSS Tooltip with Arrow in Center

Tags: html, css, tooltip, css-shapes

I would like to have the black arrow right in the center of the row `div` while also being at the bottom as it is now. Here is the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mKLJB/). Thank you.

Sample code:

```
<div class="row divisor">
    Text
    <br />
    text
</div>


.row {
    width: auto; }
    .row:before, .row:after {
        content: " ";
        display: table; }

.row { position: relative; }

.divisor {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #D8D8D8; }

.divisor:before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-left: 40px solid transparent;
    border-right: 40px solid transparent;   
    border-top: 25px solid #000; 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `left: 50%;` and `margin-left: -40px;`

```
.divisor:before {
    content: " ";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    right: 5px;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-left: 40px solid transparent;
    border-right: 40px solid transparent;
    border-top: 25px solid #000;
    margin-left: -40px;
}
```

Look at http://jsfiddle.net/iamrmin/mKLJB/3/

Comment: `left:50%` lines up the **left** edge of `.divisor:before` to 50% of `.row`.  Since you want the **middle** of `.divisor:before` to line up with 50%, you move it left half of its width. since it is 80px wide (`border-left` + `border-right`), you move it 40px to the left with `margin-left:-40px`.